# Is the latest version of CakePHP able to send heavy data from one controller to another?

Tags: php, cakephp, variable-assignment

Suppose I have a form (MY_FORM) inside a view rendered by CONTROLLER_0 wich has more forms. The action of MY_FORM is handled by CONTROLLER_1.

If I submit MY_FORM and one of the models that deals with it triggers some validation errors, I try to redirect to my original view/layout.

This redirect would switch the current controller from CONTROLLER_1 to CONTROLLER_0.

Here is my problem.. I want to get those validationErrors from one controller to another in order to be able to print them next to the coresponding inputs.

Can this be done ? If not in this way, how otherwise, while keeping this behavior of the app, or at least the appereance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it via the session, if you want.

```
$this->Session->write('validationErrors', $this->Model->validationErrors);
```

Then read it in the next controller

```
$this->Session->read('validationErrors');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'test','action' => 'index','test'=>array(10,12)));
```

and to get this data in other controller you have to put this code:

```
$data = $this->params->params['named']['test'];
pr($data);
```